# htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ok my project is to make an old static site into a dynamic one. There are about 40 pages in the old site.

The new format will be in 2 languages for now, with the possibility for more in the future.

There are 2 sets of urls actually:

1. the basic ones: /index.html, /about.html, /contact.html
2. the rest: /folder1/page1.html, /folder1/page2.html, /folder3/page3.html, etc

The client wants the 2nd language to have the same pattern as the default one:

1. the basic ones: /**language**/index.html, /**language**/about.html, /**language**/contact.html
2. the rest: /language/folder1/page1.html, /language/folder1/page2.html, /language/folder3/page3.html, etc

The basic pages i can rewrite with htaccess:

```
# default language    
RewriteRule ^about.html$ about.php?language= [NC,L]
#other language
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/about.html$ about.php?language=$1 [NC,L]
```

As for the rest of the pages i am stuck.

In my database i have saved the existing urls and their content.

For example, for the basic language:

/folder1/page1.html will be served by dynamicpage1.php?language=&url=/folder1/page1.html

/folder2/page2.html will be served by dynamicpage1.php?language=&url=/folder2/page2.html

/folder3/page3.html will be served by dynamicpage2.php?language=&url=/folder3/page3.html

And for the other language:

/([^/]+)/folder1/page1.html will be served by dynamicpage1.php?language=$1&url=/folder1/page1.html

/([^/]+)/folder2/page2.html will be served by dynamicpage1.php?language=$1&url=/folder2/page2.html

/([^/]+)/folder3/page3.html will be served by dynamicpage2.php?language=$1&url=/folder3/page3.html

How can i construct these rules?

If i try: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ subservices.php?language=$1&url=$2, it fails

Comment: 1) What do you mean "fails"? 2) what `subservices.php` script does? -- as I understand it will decide which dynamic page to run, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better specify/list possible languages in URL Rewriting rule -- it will be MUCH MORE accurate then. This rule works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^((EN|FR)/)?(.*\.html)$ /subservices.php?language=$2&url=/$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^((english|french)/)?(.*\.html)$ /subservices.php?language=$2&url=/$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Change `EN|FR` to whatever languages you do use.

- `/index.html` will be rewritten to `/subservices.php?language=&url=/index.html`
- `/FR/index.html` will be rewritten to `/subservices.php?language=FR&url=/index.html`
- `/folder1/page1.html` will be rewritten to `/subservices.php?language=&url=/folder1/page1.html`
- `/FR/folder1/page1.html` will be rewritten to `/subservices.php?language=FR&url=/folder1/page1.html`
- `/ZZ/folder1/page1.html` will be rewritten to `/subservices.php?language=&url=/ZZ/folder1/page1.html` (ZZ is not recognized as acceptable language).

Comment: i tried your code but instead of EN|FR i used english|french and i got inernal server error 500. This only works for EN i assume?

Comment: I have made small mistake (I have used useless `[]` ) -- check the rule again -- tested on my PC and have it working fine

Comment: ok i am 50% there
RewriteRule ^((english|french)/)?(.*\.html)$ /subservices.php?language=$2&url=/$3 [NC,QSA,L]

this works for /french/ directory
but in english i get 500 internal server error

i guess some other rules conflict with this one.. will try to debug and see what will i find